# Trouble with "addeventlistener" and getting statement "if statement" to run

Tags: onclicklistener, addeventlistener

I'm trying to get my game to run based on the click of a button. Please bear with me! I'm new to coding. I want when a button is clicked, to assign a variable to that button.
To recap:

- I have 3 buttons for a player to choose from, essentially rock, paper scissors.
  -the player clicks a button and it is automatically played against a randomly computer generated number
  -I cannot get from the button click to assigning a value to the player's choice variable.

```
//calls game variables
const gameChoices = ["Scalpellus","Papyrus","Lapis"];
let playerChoice = null;
let computerChoice = null;

// The computer random choice. 
function computerChooses(){
  const randomChoiceComputer = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameChoices.length); 
  //the computer chooses their "weapon" & updates computer function
  CompRandoChoice = gameChoices[randomChoiceComputer];
  return CompRandoChoice;
}

// Player chooses by clicking a button

// Defining variables for event listening, gets the button Id from HTML, calls the function for the computer's randomly generated choice
const scalpellusButton = document.getElementById("scalpellus").addEventListener("click", computerChooses);
const papyrusButton = document.getElementById("papyrus").addEventListener("click", computerChooses);
const lapisButton = document.getElementById("lapis").addEventListener("click", computerChooses);

// if statement to stores the choice from the button that was clicked
if (scalpellusButton === true) {
  playerChoice = gameChoices[0];
}
else if (papyrusButton === true) {
  playerChoice = gameChoices[1];
}
else {
  playerChoice = gameChoices[2];
}
```

Comment: Where are you _declaring_ `CompRandoChoice`?

Comment: That's a good point. I must have messed it up with all the changes I've been making! Do you have any advice on how to get from my event listeners to using that event in my if statement?

Comment: Move your `if` statement to be inside the event-listener.

Comment: I have 3 event listeners and the if Statement is dependent on the variables of the event listeners. Could you show me what you mean?